# How to detect a smartphone through JavaScript/CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, platform-detection

I've seen around the web that the best way to make a responsive design is to use CSS `@media` queries. This does not seem like a practical solution as many phones identify as `screen` and have as many pixels as desktop monitors (i.e. the iPhone 6 Plus is 1080x1920 and some Android phones have even larger sizes). So if I said `min-width: 800px;` for my desktop design, many smartphones would use those rules.

One workaround is to use `navigator.userAgent` in JavaScript to detect mobile devices, but I've also heard that this is not widely compatible.

Is there a 'best' way to determine if a user is on a mobile device (preferably with JavaScript or CSS)?

Comment: responsive design means to have best view in the screen resolution doesn't matter it is a phone, tablet or desktop ... so if you want responsive design, use @media ... all other will put you in a dead way.

Comment: It's doable with feature-detection (still not bulletproof), but ultimately CSS media queries should be more than sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this code to your page `head`, the width of the viewport won't be the the actual number of pixels, but instead something compareable to a pixel density of 96dpi:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
```

This results with a CSS width of 320 pixels on most smartphones even though their actual resolutions are higher.